# GMSURLTileLayer overlaps polyline

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS in my app. I can easly draw polyline with google map tiles. But when i add custom (OSM) TileLayer - it renders over polyline. Can't understand what sould i fix to bring my polyline back with custom tiles.

Here is the code for downloading tiles:

```
GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {
        NSString *url = [NSString
                         stringWithFormat:@"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%lu/%lu/%lu.png", (unsigned long)zoom, (unsigned long)x, (unsigned long)y];
        return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    };
    GMSURLTileLayer *layer = [GMSURLTileLayer tileLayerWithURLConstructor:urls];
    layer.map = googleMapView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem sovled by changing zIndex value of custom tile layer and polyline layer

Answer (score 0):

I set zIndex= 99, use the same code above, still do not see the custom tiles. Not sure why.

However, google sample code, SDKDemo -> tilelayer DID works, did show the floor plan overlay.

Comment: So what you're saying is that SDKDemo works. Looks more like a comment to me.